# Laravel: Delete page not found

Tags: php, laravel, destroy

My delete function is not working, the entry is not being deleted from the database, the error I receive is:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Thanks for any help.

**view:**

```
        {{ Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['fields.destroy', $data[$i]->id]]) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Usuń wpis', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger','data-toggle'=>'confirmation']) }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

**controller:**

```
public function destroy($id) {
    DB::table('fields')->where('id', $id)->delete();
    var_dump('co tam');
    exit;
    return response()->json(['success' => "Product Deleted successfully.", 'tr' => 'tr_' . $id]);
  }
```

**routes:**

```
Route::get('/home/twojedzialki', 'twojedzialkiController@index')->name('twojedzialki.index');
Route::delete('/home/twojedzialki/{$id}', 'twojedzialkiController@destroy')-> name('fields.destroy');
```

But this works: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/twojedzialki/4

I know that the ID is valid.

Thanks for helping me find the source of the issue.

Comment: check your formatting again... it looks messag below `return response()->json(['success' => "Product Deleted successfully.".....`

Answer (score 2):

This

```
Route::delete('/home/twojedzialki/{$id}', 'twojedzialkiController@destroy')-> name('fields.destroy');
```

should be this

```
Route::delete('/home/twojedzialki/{id}', 'twojedzialkiController@destroy')-> name('fields.destroy');
```

without `$`